# Why do I get Unexpected Token , error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing application for mobile device on Ionic framework. So I have just got 'Ionic white screen of death' on my android. I get unexpected token , error. Ok, I opened inspector in Google Chrome and there is what I got

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEPgT.png)

As you can see, there is an error in main.js file. I've found this file. It is in www/build folder. So this **Main.js** is required for building application for android.
Ok, so I can't edit this file because when I try to build app again all my edits get undo. I can see origin file without my edits. Why is this happening?

**!! I use libary for image editing LowPoly -> [Link](https://github.com/jrainlau/LowPolifier)**

**triangle.html**

```
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Trianglify</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content class="triangle" text-center>

<button ion-button block outline (click)="takePicture()">Take a picture</button><br>
<button ion-button color="secondary" block outline style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px;" (click)="transformPHToTriangle(base64Image);">Transform</button>

<img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image">
</ion-content>
```

**Triangle.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import  LowPoly from 'lowpoly';

@IonicPage()

@Component({
    selector: 'page-triangle',
    templateUrl: 'triangle.html',
})

export class TrianglePage {

    public base64Image: string = './home_img/portrait.jpg';

    constructor(private camera: Camera, public navCtrl: NavController,         public navParams: NavParams) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad TrianglePage');
    }

    takePicture() {
        this.camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000
        }).then((imageData) => {
        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        });
    }

transformPHToTriangle(photo) {
    new LowPoly(photo, {EDGE_DETECT_VALUE:80, 
    POINT_RATE:0.075, 
    POINT_MAX_NUM:3500, 
    BLUR_SIZE:2, 
    EDGE_SIZE:8, 
    PIXEL_LIMIT: 350000}).init().then((data) => {
    this.base64Image = data;
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why link off to an image, when you can put it in the post itself?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Also, please post a [mcve] of your code?

Comment: @Bergi, code posted, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library expects you to pass it through babel. See docs : https://github.com/jrainlau/LowPolifier#usage

## Fix

Use `babel-loader`.

## More

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader